# Rollover image with link to next php

Tags: php, rollover

I have a rollover image but i was unable to place in the link which will bring the user to the next php page. Should I use onclick ?

```
onclick="window.location.href='SearchCD.php
```

Here are my codes on the home page.

```
<?php
$backgroundpic = "Background.jpeg";
$searchpic = "Search icon.png";
$searchhoverpic = "Search icon with search word.jpg";
?>

<a href="#" class="searchbutton"></a>

<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

body {
background-image: url('<?php echo $backgroundpic;?>');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
background-attachment:fixed;
width: 100%;
}
.searchbutton {
display: block;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background-image: url('<?php echo $searchpic;?>');
}
.searchbutton:hover {
display: block;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background-image: url('<?php echo $searchhoverpic;?>');
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you be more precise .

Comment: @AniruddhaChakraborty, OP CAN use PHP within **inline** CSS in `.php` file.

Comment: @Zan sorry, i mean on my home page i have the rollover image but when the image is click, it should go to the next php page. I'm using onclick for buttons. Doe sit work the same for rolloverimage ?

Comment: @Adam, sorry what do you mean OP CAN ?